# NameError in Python program even though it seems to be setup correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I copied this program from the Mission Python book:

```
room_map = [[1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1]]

WIDTH = 800 # window size
HEIGHT = 800

top_left_x = 100
top_left_y = 150

DEMO_OBJECTS = [images.floor, images.pillar]

room_height = 7
room_width = 5

def draw():
    for y in range(room_height):
        for x in range(room_width):
            image_to_draw = DEMO_OBJECTS[room_map[y][x]]
            screen.blit(image_to_draw,
                        (top_left_x + (x * 30),
                        top_left_y + (y * 30) - image_to_draw.get_height()))
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/escape/listing3-5.py", line 15, in <module>
    DEMO_OBJECTS = [images.floor, images.pillar]
NameError: name 'images' is not defined
```

I think maybe I should import Images or some similar package but the book doesn't mention doing that so I'm not sure. The python file is in the correct location and the images folder containing my images is in the same folder. Have I missed anything obvious?

Comment: The error message is `name 'images' is not defined`. If that error surprises you, where do you think `images` is defined?

Comment: Try to `import images` or `from file_name import images` (file_name is where images is defined) and see if it works

Comment: Try to copy the whole project, or at least the whole file. If this is just a notebook/tutorial pages, they might introduce only some part of codes. Find the whole source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was trying to run the program through IDLE. I was supposed to use Pygame Zero to run it though. It works when I execute the command `pgzrun listing3-5.py`.

I suppose Pygame Zero already has `images` defined.